# SAP HANA: "Invalid schema name" error while schema is present

Tags: jdbc, hana

We are stuck with this since a long time and not able to blame anything yet. We are connecting to SAP HANA database through JDBC driver, for some cases it's constantly failing with "invalid schema name" even if schema is present in the database and we have full rights to it. The SQL query which fails from the Java application runs smoothly from HANA Studio. This is not frequently reproducible with every schema but it fails regularly for one schema with specific database connection.

Is this observed by anyone ever? Upgrading JDBC driver would help?

precise error with error code

> com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [362] (at 2278): invalid schema name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: The edited error message by itself doesn't allow for an error analysis. Please do share the code that leads to the error or an un-modified JDBC trace. Since SAP HANA Studio uses JDBC too, it's likely that this is due to a error in your application code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but we had similar issues and were able to resolve them by specifying the database name in the JDBC URL when connecting to the database:

```
String server = "servername.domain.com";
String instance = "00";
String database = "SBODEMONL";
String dbUsername = "SYSTEM";
String dbPassword = "xxxxxx";
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sap://" + server + ":3" + instance + "15/?currentschema=" + database + "&user=" + dbUsername + "&password=" + dbPassword;
java.sql.Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
```

See also: https://scn.sap.com/thread/3217656 for more information on JDBC URL parameters.